# Does Alexa Skill Kit listen on other port of SSL (besides 443)

Tags: php, apache, ssl, webserver, alexa-skills-kit

I created a skill from Alexa skill kits on Amazon development. The API endpoint is from my home server running PHP. It works fine but now I have another server running and is listening on port 444 (with SSL). I use same domain name and SSL certificate on this new server (Apache). But now Alexa skill kit doesn't seem to send anything to my API endpoint.

I don't know if the Alexa skill kit only sends request over 443 only or my set up is wrong?

For example, my current working node is: `https://myserver.com/api/main.php`

My new server: `https://myserver.com:444/api/main.php`

The reason for this weird 444 port is port 443 is taken on my home public ip (port forwarding). So I need my public IP to forward request to my new server if it sees port 444. I'm new to all this so please excuse all my noob set up here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To my understanding the Alexa service is restricted to using API endpoints with port 443 only. I had come to this conclusion after some testing, then stumbled upon this blog article when searching for answers to this before:
https://freebusy.io/blog/getting-started-with-alexa-app-development-for-amazon-echo-using-dot-net

> The Alexa service is strict regarding app endpoints. It will only call
>   out using HTTPS on port 443 whether it's calling an app during
>   development or deployed to production.
>
> -Stefan at FreeBusy.io

However, you can make requests from a Lambda function without such restrictions and could achieve making requests to both ports on HTTPS or HTTP.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I ended up using 443 anyway